# password_digest error message on my first model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

After watch Lynda's tutorial about rails Im trying to start my first app. First, I have created the database. The development and the test one. After that I did create my first Model. Using the name Usuario. Using its migration file, I have created the table Usuarios. Inside it, I have: id, nome, login, senha, ativo, created_at and updated_at. Since this is my admin users table, I wanna start doing some tests on the console. So I set the nome value doing:

```
usuario = Usuario.new
usuario = "Alex"
```

And after that I tried to save:

```
usuario.save
```

Now, I keep getting the message: **NoMethodError: undefined method `password_digest'**

And this is my model Usuario code:

```
class Usuario < ApplicationRecord

    validates_presence_of :nome
    validates_length_of :nome, :within => 5..255
    validates_presence_of :login
    validates_length_of :login, :within => 5..50
    validates_uniqueness_of :login
    validates_presence_of :senha
    validates_length_of :senha, :within => 5..20
    validates_presence_of :ativo
end
```

I removed the comment on this line of Gemfile too:

```
gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'
```

But Im not using the **has_secure_password** instruction on my class yet. So, why am I getting this error message on the console? I even tried to remove thoses validations from my model but I still get that error message. Why? Am I missing some important step?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with `usario = "Alex"`? Shouldn't it be `usario.name = "Alex"`? Also, did you restart your console after you removed password validation check?

Comment: Sorry, I did it right on the console but wrote it here wrong. Sorry.